# Is it possible to load in a local storage value into a tweet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, local-storage

If I am using JS to create a new window/tweet to share, can I pull in information from my local storage as well?

```
<li class="fa fa-twitter" onclick="window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=I just score X on this game!', 'newwindow', 'width=300, height=250')"></li>
```

We currently store a user's score in LocalStorage with a value of `score`. We even print it on the page. Would there ba away to upload it into the tweet?

So far I've tried using a span, and appending the score, but this breaks the URL.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the broken URL look like? Might be some URL escaping issues from injecting a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add that value using concatenation:

```
<li class="fa fa-twitter" onclick="window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=I just score ' + localStorage['score'] + ' on this game!', 'newwindow', 'width=300, height=250')"></li>
```

Comment: Sorry, tried to accept this but then it said SO went down for maintenance. This fixed my problem! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Inline js  is terrible :)

Try this

```
<li class="fa fa-twitter" onclick="onClick"></li>

function onClick(){
   var val = localStorage.get('something');
   window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=I just score X on this"+val+" game!',
   'newwindow',
   'width=300,height=250')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, can you definitely do this. I wouldn't use inline `onclick` attribute for this purpose. Simply, add event listener, and you open the window with user score from `localStorage`, along with your text.

```
<li class="fa fa-twitter" id="tweet"></li>
<script>
$('#tweet').on('click', function(e){
    var score = localStorage.getItem('userScore');
    var tweetTxt = 'I just scored ' + score  + ' on this game!';
    window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='+encodeURIComponent(tweetTxt), 'newwindow', 'width=300, height=250')
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep things clear and simple.

```js
tweetScore = function() {
  var score = localStorage.getItem('score');
  var text = 'I just score '+ score + ' on this game!';
  /* var options = 
     { width: 300; height:200, ... }
  */
  var url = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='+text;
  
  window.open(url, 'newwindow', 'width=300,height=200');
  // or fetch them from options
  return 0;
}
```

```html
<li class="fa fa-twitter" onclick="tweetScore()">
  tweet
</li>
```

Btw, you can also seperate the url forming from `tweetScore()` function.

```
urlCreator = function(foo) {
//some operations
//var url = foo+..
return url;
}
```

then use it's return value in `tweetScore()`

```
tweetScore = function() {
  var score = localStorage.getItem('score');
  var text = 'I just score '+ score + ' on this game!';
  /* var options = 
     { width: 300; height:200, ... }
  */
  var url = createUrl(text);
  ...
```

you can also extend it by passing arguments - that will allow you to tweet lots of things, not just scores.

```
tweetThis(arg1) {
  //process arg1
  //createUrl
}
```